# python crawler problems when using aiohttp

Tags: python, web-crawler, aiohttp

I'm a beginner in web spider and i am so confused these days when using aiohttp.
Here is my code:

```
header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1207.1 Safari/537.1',
              'Referer': 'https://www.mzitu.com/',
               'Accept': "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
               'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip',
     }

class MZiTu(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.timeout = 5
        self.file_path = 'D:\mzitu'  
        self.common_page_url = 'https://www.mzitu.com/page/'
        self.total_page_num = 0
        self.end_album_num = 0
        self.session = None

    async def start(self):
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=header) as mzt.session:
            for page in range(1, self.total_page_num+1):
                await self.crawlAlbum(self.common_page_url, page)

    async def crawlAlbum(self, common_url, page_num):
        page_url = self.common_page_url + str(page_num)
        async with self.session.get(page_url, timeout=self.timeout) as resp:
            html = await resp.text()
            bsop = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
            album_items = bsop.find('ul', {'id': 'pins'}).findAll('li')
            for item in album_items:
                try:
                    album_title = item.find('img').attrs['alt']
                    album_url = item.find('a').attrs['href']
                    if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(self.file_path, album_title)):
                        os.mkdir(os.path.join(self.file_path, album_title))
                    os.chdir(os.path.join(self.file_path, album_title))
                    await self.crawlImgs(album_url)
                except:
                    continue

    async def crawlImgs(self, album_url):
        self.end_album_num = await self.getAlbumTotalNum(album_url)
        for i in range(1, self.end_album_num+1):
            img_page_url = album_url + str(i)
            async with self.session.get(img_page_url, timeout=self.timeout) as resq:
                html = await resq.text()
                bsop = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
                try:
                    img_url = bsop.find('div', {'class': 'main-image'}).find('img').attrs['src']
                    await self.downloadImg(i, img_url)
                except:
                    continue

    async def getAlbumTotalNum(self, album_url):
        async with self.session.get(album_url, timeout=self.timeout) as resq:
            html = await resq.text()
            bsop = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
            total_num = int(bsop.find('div', {'class': 'nav-links'}).findAll('a', {'class': 'page-numbers'})[-2].text)
            return total_num

    async def downloadImg(self,index, img_url):
        async with self.session.get(img_url, timeout=self.timeout) as resq:
            content = await resq.read()
            async with aiofiles.open(str(index)+'.jpg', 'wb') as f:
                await f.write(content)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mzt = MZiTu()
    mzt.total_page_num = 2
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    to_do = [mzt.start()]
    wait_future = asyncio.wait(to_do)
    loop.run_until_complete(wait_future)
    loop.close()
```

my code return directly at the first line below,why? so confused

```
async def getAlbumTotalNum(self, album_url):
        async with self.session.get(album_url, timeout=self.timeout) as resq:
            html = await resq.text()
            bsop = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
            total_num = int(bsop.find('div', {'class': 'nav-links'}).findAll('a', {'class': 'page-numbers'})[-2].text)
            return total_num
```

i can't find any errors in my program. 
so confused.
so confused.
if there are some Learning materials about aiohttp and asyncio, i feel so difficult.

Comment: Sorry, we [can't accept images of code or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Post those as *text*, so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers. I am really not sure what you mean by *my code return directly here*.

Comment: Don't assign your session to `mzt.session`; if you are going to use a non-local name in `with ... as <target>`, use `self.session` at the very least. Don't use bare `except: continue` handlers, ever, you now have no record of what is going wrong, and you'll be catching `asyncio.CancelledError` exceptions too.

Comment: What is `header` set to? We'll need a proper [mcve] to reproduce your problem.

Comment: sorry,  i have replaced my image with text.

Comment: When I set `header = {}` at the top, add the required imports (`asyncio`, `aiohttp` and `aiofiles`) and replace the blanket `except: continue` blocks with `except Exception: traceback.print_exc(); continue` blocks, I get a `asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError` exception in `crawlAlbum`; the site is not answering within the time limit.

Comment: I am greatly grateful for your help to me and i have added the header in my question

Comment: The real issue here is that your BeautifulSoup queries are incorrect, but you can't see them because you use a blanket `except:` handler. Don't do that, make sure you can actually understand what bugs there may be in your code.

Comment: In `getAlbumTotalNum()`, `total_num = int(bsop.find('div', {'class': 'nav-links'}).findAll('a', {'class': 'page-numbers'})[-2].text)` throws `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll'` because `bsop.find('div', {'class': 'nav-links'})` returned `None`.

Comment: Pro tip: use the `.select()` method with a CSS selector instead: `bsop.select('div.nav-links a.page-numbers')` gives you the same elements as the nested `find().findAll()` call, provided there actually are such elements in the page.

Comment: Also, can you please find another site to use when asking questions like these? That site looks decidedly Not Suitable For Work when I try out pages in my browser.

Comment: so strange,   the html elements of the page have been changed.

Comment: Right, so now the query is `div.pagenavi a'`, not `div.nav-links a.page-numbers`. That's why you don't want to blanket-suppress all exceptions.

Comment: This is the motivation for my studying python crawler. so awkward

Comment: When the program executes to first line of function getAlbumTotalNum, Why return directly？Although I have tried to debug it

Comment: What are you using to debug? Don't confuse task switching with exiting, you never reach the code in the `with` block if you don't take into account that `await` is going to lead to the event loop moving to another task.

Comment: Thanks very much. My English is very bad, it maybe gives you some trouble. The information on asyncio and aiohttp online  is very scarce. Can you provide some good study advice?

Comment: Nothing you were doing wrong here has anything much to do with Asyncio. Read up on general concurrency techniques (using queues, events, locks, etc.) and coroutines perhaps? That'll be needed much more when coding asynchronous I/O programs.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.The program seems to have some problems (Image cannot be downloaded)  and I will try to debug again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is that you are using [pokemon exception handling](https://blog.codinghorror.com/new-programming-jargon/), you really *don't want to catch them all*.

Catch specific exceptions, *only*, or at least only catch `Exception` and make sure to re-raise `asyncio.CancelledError` (you don't want to block task cancellations), and log or print the exceptions that are raised so you can further clean up your handler. As a quick fix, I replaced your `try:... except: continue` blocks with:

```
try:
    # ...
except asyncio.CancelledError:
    raise
except Exception:
    traceback.print_exc()
    continue
```

and added `import traceback` at the top. When you then run your code, you see why your code is failing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 43, in crawlAlbum
    await self.crawlImgs(album_url)
  File "test.py", line 51, in crawlImgs
    self.end_album_num = await self.getAlbumTotalNum(album_url)
  File "test.py", line 72, in getAlbumTotalNum
    total_num = int(bsop.find('div', {'class': 'nav-links'}).findAll('a', {'class': 'page-numbers'})[-2].text)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll'
```

Either the way the site marked up links changed, or the site uses Javascript to alter the DOM in a browser after loading the HTML. Either way, using a blanket `except:` clause without logging the error hides such issues from you and make it really hard to debug.

I'd at least add some logging to record what URL the code was trying to parse when exceptions occur, so you can replicate the issue in an interactive, non-asyncio setup and try out different approaches to parse the pages.

Rather than use `.find()` and `.findAll()` calls, use [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) the find the correct elements:

```
links = bsop.select(f'div.pagenavi a[href^="{album_url}"] span')
return 1 if len(links) < 3 else int(links[-2].string)
```

The above uses the current URL to limit the search to the specific `span` elements with a `a` element parent that have `href` attribute whose value at least starts with the current page URL.

Note that the above is not the only problem however, when that one is fixed, the next exception is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 59, in crawlImgs
    img_url = bsop.find('div', {'class': 'main-image'}).find('img').attrs['src']
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

This one is actually caused by your incorrect URL handling for albums, assuming that they'll always end in `/`. Correct this:

```
async def crawlImgs(self, album_url):
    end_album_num = await self.getAlbumTotalNum(album_url)
    if album_url[-1] != '/':
        album_url += '/'
    for i in range(1, end_album_num + 1):
        img_page_url = album_url + str(i)
        # ...
```

You do *not* want to set `album_num` as an attribute on `self` however! The class instance state is shared between tasks, while you don't actually create multiple tasks in your code (it is all one sequential task at the moment), you want to avoid altering shared state.